# easyRTC Error connecting to socket.io server

Tags: php, node.js

I am trying to run nodejs on php file.

```
<script src="htps://xxx.com:8445/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="htps://xxx.com:8445/easyrtc/easyrtc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Server.js :

```
// Load required modules
var https   = require("https");     // https server core module
var fs      = require("fs");        // file system core module
var express = require("express");   // web framework external module
var io      = require("socket.io"); // web socket external module
var easyrtc = require("../");   // EasyRTC external module

// Setup and configure Express http server. Expect a subfolder called "static" to be the web root.
var httpApp = express();
httpApp.use(express.static(__dirname + ":8445"));

// Start Express https server on port 8445
var webServer = https.createServer(
{
    key:  fs.readFileSync("/etc/apache2/ssl/xxx.com.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/apache2/ssl/xxx.com.crt")
},
httpApp).listen(8445);

// Start Socket.io so it attaches itself to Express server
var socketServer = io.listen(webServer, {"log level":1});

// Start EasyRTC server
var rtc = easyrtc.listen(httpApp, socketServer);
```

ERROR :
[image]

Nodejs works but i got an error like that. If i didnt use PHP, it can work.

Comment: why did you hide the white in the error? Is the port 8445 displayed there?

Comment: no there is domain name and extension

Comment: @slowdeath007 i mean google.com/socket.io ..................... i have no idea why port does not return

Comment: can you try navigating with your browser on this link? htps://xxx.com:8445/socket.io/socket.io.js? Also you have typed htps instead of https or http

Comment: @slowdeath007 i had written https but SO does not accept https links so i wrote htps. And i tried to navigate ur link on my browser and returns some javascript codes.

Comment: can you show me where you initiate the socket.io connection on the client side? It seems you have forgotten to put the port in there. I am still not 100% sure since this is the first time I am seeing this problem. Also it would help to know if node is run behind a reverse proxy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146646/discussion-between-slowdeath007-and-ozgun-unlu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone coming from google with this problem, easyRTC was assuming the http server and the ws server was on the same url/port. To fix the issue the method `easyrtc.setSocketUrl("https://thedomain.com.tr:8445");` was required to run after including easyRTC